# Hibernate Merge() causing duplicate records in two sessions

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, merge

One user opens a screen and is trying to create a record.
Another user opens same screen and is trying to create the record.
I am using spring transactions.

The code which is responsible for insert/update uses hibernate merge().

Expectation: when a user has already created that record, another user should not be able to do so.

issue: two records can inserted in the database, one for each user. how to resolve this without change database table.

Comment: Some example code perhaps? Show your code that is responsible for inserting/updating.

Comment: Without changing the database table, I don't see how you could have such a guarantee. A unique constraint should be created. The only alternative I see is to check if the record exist, then create the record. But that will only work if a single process inserts in this table, and if the checkThenInsert method is protected by a mutex.

Comment: What makes a record unique? It would be easier to understand with an example.